# Does print function have more 'privilege' in python

Tags: python, printing, global-variables, local-variables

```
def func_print_x():
    ## x += 1    ## if uncomment this line, it will raise UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
    print x
if __name__ = '__main__':
    x = 4
    func_print_x()
```

In the function **func_print_x()**, there are two rules:

1. for the line '**x += 1**', the variable **x** is regard as local variable;
2. when come to the line '**print x**', the variable **x** seem to be global variable.

Does **print** function have more 'privilege'?

Comment: No, `x` becomes a local variable *when you try to assign to it within the function*, as you do with `+=` here. You can *use* the global variable `x` however you want within the function, as long as you don't try to assign to it somewhere else.

Comment: @Marius Oh, I see.   '**don't try to assign to it**'  will be OK!    `print x + 1` works fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
def f():
    global s
    print s
    s = "That's clear."
    print s 


s = "Python is great!" 
f()
print s
```

o/p

```
Python is great!
That's clear.
That's clear.
```

but whne you do not have `global`

```
def f(): 
    print s
    s = "Me too."
    print s


s = "I hate spam." 
f()
print s
```

o/p

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 's' referenced before assignment
```

You will get the above error if you try to assign some values to `s`

if you try to print the value of `s`  it will be printed inside the function